# How to create a transition matrix out of a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, transition

I have customers at a specific location. The customer may change the location from year to year. I would like to create a transition matrix that shows me the customers that transited from one location to another.
Tidy dataframe:

```
year cust  loc
2019  C1   LA
2019  C2   LA
2019  C3   LB
2019  C4   LC
2019  C5   LA
2019  C6   LA
2020  C1   LB
2020  C2   LA
2020  C4   LC
2020  C5   LC
2020  C6   LC
2020  C7   LD


    LA    LB    LC    LD    dorp
LA        C1  C5,C6
LB                           C3
LC
LD
```

I am looking for an elegant way to achieve that in pandas. Any clever idea where extensive nested looping is not needed?

Comment: Is this just for 2 years or do you need all transitions Y -> Y+1

Comment: what;s `dorp` in the output?

Comment: @ALollz there would be a separate transition matrix for every Y -> Y+1

Comment: @Quang Hoang drop means that that the customer did not show up at any location in the following year (e.g. C3 in 2020). Thus, its being dropped.

Comment: This looks like a pivot problem/solution!